# Finding the infinite limit using definitions

Tags: analysis, limits

I would really need help proving the following limit using the definitions. My textbook gives me a solution but with very minimal explanation and I'm completely lost.

This is the limit I have to find.

> $$\lim_{x\to1^+} \frac{x}{x-1}$$

Comment: You have a fraction whose numerator goes to a positive number strictly greater than $0$ (in this case, the numerator approaches $1$), while the denominator approaches $0$ from the positive real side... Think of the graph for $\frac{1}{x-1}$ and consider what happens as you trace the graph toward $1$ (from the right-hand side).

Comment: @Clayton but I have to prove this using the definitions. Like I know the answer is positive infinity.

Comment: Of course you should use the definition; why do it any other way? The graph gives you an idea of what to look for in these problems.

Comment: RTP;$ \forall r>0 \exists s>0\;(\forall x\in (1,1+s) \;(x/(x-1)>r).$   Proof: Let $s= \min (1,1/r) .$ Then $\forall x\in (1,1+s) \; (x/(x-1)>x/s\geq x/(1/r)>1/(1/r)=r).$

Comment: @Michelle Drolet If you are ok you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $C>0$ and set $\delta := \frac{1}{C} > 0 $. For $x \in (1,1+\delta)$ we have that ${\frac{x}{x-1}} \geq \frac{1}{\delta} = C$. Thus by definition $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} \frac{x}{x-1} = \infty $.

Comment: But how did you figure out to set δ:=1/C and why is x/x−1≥1/δ

Comment: A lot of the time when doing these questions, you do some calculations first to see what you need your $\delta$ to be and then retrospectively fix its value at the beginning when you write your solution up. This one is a particularly easy example, but in more complex cases you'll have to write some things down first.

Comment: It's the calculation part that I would need some help with.

Comment: That inequality comes from the fact that $ | x | = x > 1$ and $ | x-1 | = x-1 < \delta$, which implies $ | \frac{1}{x-1} | > \frac{1}{\delta}$. Combining them gives the inequality.

Comment: I might be missing something but why is x > 1

Comment: I think you need to take away the absolute sign. Right now, you are proving the limit tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: The limit you have been asked to calculate is a one-sided limit - in particular the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from above. This means you are looking at values of $x$ in the range $(1,1+\delta)$ for small $\delta$.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we guess that $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x}{x - 1} = +\infty$$

By definition, we need to show $\forall M > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$ $$\frac{x}{x - 1} > M$$

Now we work backwards, observe $$\frac{x}{x - 1} = \frac{x - 1 + 1}{x - 1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x - 1}$$

So we need to find $\delta > 0$ such that $$\frac{1}{x - 1} > M - 1$$

Without loss of generality we may assume $M > 1$, since if the $\delta$ works for a larger $M$, it will also works for a smaller $M$.

Using $x > 1$, we have $x - 1 > 0$, so

$$x < \frac{1}{M - 1} + 1$$

Since $\frac{1}{M - 1} < \frac{1}{M}$,

$$x < \frac{1}{M} + 1$$

Recall that $x$ satisfies the assumption that $x < 1 + \delta$.

So taking $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$ and we are done.